# How to update field when new item is created from another list in SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

This is the first time I'm using SharePoint workflow. I have two lists

tb_device which has

- device_id
- device_name
- availability_status

and another list is tb_user_borrow which has

- id_device which lookup on tb_device
- borrow_date
- status

What I want is, where the user inserts a new item to tb_user_borrow with device_id selected, tb_device is updated the availability_status to "No".

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo for your reference.

[image]